# How to set python3 as default

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu, python-3.9

I recently installed python3.9.6 on ubuntu
and it all seemed to work
but when enter python3 on the terminal it shows python3.8.5, not python3.9.6
I want to type in python, python3, or python3.9 to open python3.9.6
can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Check python version on terminal - `python --version`

Get root user privileges. On terminal type - `sudo su`

Write down the root user password.

Execute this command to switch to python 3.6.

`update-alternatives --install  /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 1`

Check python version - python --version

Comment: that just made it so that if I enter python it opens python3.8.5

Comment: Can't you delete the previous python versions and install the 3.9.6 version again? This will make it the only python version so if you enter `python` it will auto point to python 3.9

Comment: You mean I need to delete python3 in /usr/bin ?

Comment: Make sure you dont want the python versions. If you don't use this: 
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding a permanent alias:

1. Open your .bashrc file: `vim ~/.bashrc`
2. Add this to the end of the file:

`alias sudo="sudo "`  (credit to https://askubuntu.com/a/22043)

`alias python="INSERT-PATH-TO-PYTHON-EXE-HERE"`

`alias python3="INSERT-PATH-TO-PYTHON-EXE-HERE"`

`alias python3.9="INSERT-PATH-TO-PYTHON-EXE-HERE"`

3. If you have any of the following: .bash_aliases, .bash_login, .profile. Add to it instead
4. Reload .bashrc: `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: @이근윤 You can try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/22043). I already added it to my answer.